# Common Multiple With For Loop

Tags: javascript

I want to get the common multiple in any given array, the problem i think is in my loop condition i dont want j to be less than 30, i want j to keep multiplying until the common multiple is found you can see the desired output down, how can i do this? thanks in advance.

```
function m(arr){
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log(`when arr[i] = `, i);
    for(let j = arr[arr.length - 1]; j < 30; j += arr[arr.length - 1]) {
      if(j % arr[i] === 0) console.log(j)
    }
  }
}

m([2,3,4,5])
```

this code outputs:

```
when arr[i] =  2
10
20

when arr[i] =  3
15

when arr[i] =  4
20

when arr[i] =  5
5
10
15
20
25
```

desired output

```
when arr[i] =  2
60
when arr[i] =  3
60
when arr[i] =  4
60
when arr[i] =  5
60
```

Comment: you can use the statement `break;` when you found one :)

Comment: @Sysix if i use break it will outputs only 5, plus i want to get rid of the `j < 30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Prosy Arceno's suggestion extended a little.
Thanks Prosy.

```js
function m(arr) {

    let m = multiply( arr ) 

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`when arr[i] = `, i);

   
    for (let j = arr[ arr.length - 1 ] ; j < m ; j++) {
      let result = arr.every(function (element) {
        return j % element === 0;
      });
      if (result) { console.log(j); break }
    }
  }
}

multiply =( arr )=>{
    let m = 1 
    arr.map(  element =>{ m = m * element  }    )
    return m  

}

m([2, 3, 4, 5 , 18]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your general approach is a bit problematic. Your inner for loop searches for the first common multiple of your current `arr[i]` and the last element of the array `arr[arr.length-1]`.

In your example, this boils down to the inner loop logging a `10` because it is the first common multiple of `2` and `5`.

There are many ways to solve your problem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)

Answer (score 1):

You may use every method of Array.

```js
function m(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`when arr[i] = `, i);
    for (let j = arr[ arr.length - 1 ] ; j < 100; j++) {
      let result = arr.every(function (element) {
        return j % element === 0;
      });
      if (result) { console.log(j);  } 
    }
  }
}

m([2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

```
function m(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`when arr[i] = `, i);
    for (let j = 5; j < 100; j++) {
      let result = arr.every(function (element) {
        return j % element === 0;
      });
      if (result) console.log(j);
    }
  }
}

m([2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: I want to get rid of `j < 100` because in bigger arrays this wont work

Comment: Use the product of all the elements in your array as max instead of 100

Comment: Thank you so much @ProsyArceno